# Using spark ML models outside of spark [hdfs DistributedFileSystem could not be instantiated]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs, apache-spark-ml

I've been trying to follow along things blog post:

https://www.phdata.io/exploring-spark-mllib-part-4-exporting-the-model-for-use-outside-of-spark/

Using spark 2.1 with built in Hadoop 2.7 run locally I can save a model:

```
trainedModel.save("mymodel.model"))
```

However if I try to load the model from a regular scala (sbt) shell hdfs fails to load.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.ml.{PipelineModel, Predictor}

val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[1]").setAppName("myApp"))

val model = PipelineModel.load("mymodel.model")
```

I get this is error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem could not be instantiated
```

Is it in fact possible to use a spark model without calling spark-submit, or spark-shell? The article I linked to was the only one I'd seen mentioning such functionality.

My build.sbt is using the following dependencies:

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.1.0",
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.7.0"
```

In both cases I am using Scala 2.11.8.

Edit: Okay it looks including this was the source of the problem

```
"org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.7.0"
```

I removed that line and the problem went away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
trainedModel.write.overwrite().save("mymodel.model"))
```

Also if your model is saved locally, you can remove hdfs in your configuration. This should prevent spark from attempting to instantiate hdfs.

Comment: if your model is saved locally,you can remove hdfs in your configuration.

Comment: From [The API docs] (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.util.MLWritable)

`def save(path: String): Unit`
"Saves this ML instance to the input path, a shortcut of write.save(path)

So it would seem like it shouldn't make any sort of difference. Also the issue seems to be with PipelineModel.load which wants to instantiate HDFS before even reading the path it is given.

Comment: Never mind, it seems to be working now. Once I removed hdfs from the configuration it stopped trying to load hdfs. Thanks! Not sure if changing from save to write.save was what made a difference or not. If you add the comment around removing hdfs I can accept your answer.